# webservices or xml servers or better options for a designing an intelligent database server

Tags: xml

Below is a design choice I need to make and I am looking for some suggestions that would help me out :

Requirement : 
I have a simple client applciation that reads data from xml files and displays the data retrieved.
I had these xmls till now in my local file system, and I developed the sample client application using them.

Problem :

I intend to place these files on internet (secured), and read them from internet.

```
Reason why I want to do so is because my client applciation will be running on different machines at different places , and so reading from internet is much logical I believe.
Also this data is my client's copyright protected, so i need to put it in some location that is secured , at least password protected.
    The XML content stored needs to be processed before being presented to client.
```

I thought webservices could be a good choice, but I have never worked with it before.

So my question is :

For the given requirement what would you guys suggest ?

1. Should I go for Webservices ?
2. If I use XML servers, can I add another layer to for processing these xmls(will this be     a better choice) ?
3. Are there any other frameworks/techonologies that i should
   go through before making any decision.

What should my key points of concerns should be before taking a decision.

Please shoot out if my explanation is not clear enough or further information is required to suggest.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Services, would be with out a Doubt the best Option. The reason for this is simple; over the years Web Services have quickly become a significant technology in the evolution of the Web and distributed computing (which is what you said you are going to be doing "client application will be running on different machines at different places"), at least since the early 2000's after the IT bubble.

Web services are primarily a technique that allows different server systems to talk to each other and exchange information. The great thing about web services is that they leverage the data independence of XML to solve integration problems when dealing with firewalls. They are wrappers that map to a multitude of software programs, middle ware systems, database management systems and stand alone applications.

If you are new to web services, make sure you read up on it and explore SOAP/WSDL/UDDI and since you already know XML you can skip that part.

Web Services will change the way we view the WEB. For example, say you booked a flight for San Pedro, Brazil. Well with web services, you could(in the near future) book your flight, reserve your table registration at a restaurant, set your hotel room, and purchase tickets to a local attraction, all from the same website....

Sorry for the RANT!

Here is a little more info, on this incredibly vast topic. [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Services)

Comment: I am really ashamed and greatfull, shamefull for I did not learn such an amazing thing till now, greatfull , for learning atleast now !!! Thanks for the inputs !!!

Comment: don't be ashamed, lol. I don't know half of the things people post on this site. Learning is a constant thing man...If something is hard or difficult, that means its worth doing. Also if this was useful for you, don't forget to give and up vote/mark it as the answer =) Glad I could be of assistance.